# Cast error from (Any hashable Any) in Swift to NSMutableDictionary in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, casting, nsmutabledictionary

I have an Objective C method which expects the parameters passed to it be of the type NSMutableDictionary. I have another Swift file and a Swift method from which I need to pass a structure which is of type, (AnyHashable: Any)() , to my Objective C method which needs the same in NSMutableDictionary format. I have tried casting and other approaches, but I couldnt find the answer.

//Objective C method belongs to UserLogin class

```
    -(void)loginWithUserData:(NSMutableDictionary *)userLoginData{
      // Do something
      //Get data from Swift file here
     }
```

//Swift function from which I need to call the Objective C method and pass the data

```
    var data = [AnyHashable: Any]()
    var ObjClass = UserLogin()
    ObjClass.loginWithUserData(userLoginData: data)
```

How should this be casted as? Im using Swift 3.

Comment: Why does `loginWithUserData` expect an `NSMutableDictionary` - It should expect an `NSDictionary` and then things should just work.  If you can't change the Objective-C then you will need to actually create an `NSMutableDictionary` in Swift; you can't simply cast it

Comment: Unfortunately I cant change Objective C method. I can however make Swift code to conform to NSMutableDictionary. I was using AnyHashable since that was the paradigm followed in Swift codebase Im working on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swift dictionaries are immutable, so you can't simply cast a Swift dictionary to an `NSMutableDictionary`.

Ideally, `loginWithUserData` would expect an `NSDictionary`, not an `NSMutableDictionary`; it isn't good design for the function to mutate the dictionary.  If the parameter type is `NSDictionary` then you could still pass an `NSMutableDictionary`.

If you can't change the Objective-C function then you will need to create an `NSMutableDictionary` in Swift:

```
var data = NSMutableDictionary()
```

Comment: That's true. Thanks for the explanation.